# patchwork 'ncol' Error: Theme element `ncol` is not defined in the element hierarchy

Tags: r, ggplot2, patchwork

I am trying to plot `6` `ggplot` objects with `patchwork` such that it plots `3` ggplot objects in each row. Upon running the code below; I get an error while running `Final.Plot`. How can this be fixed? On a side note the object `patchwork` works fine  on its own as intended.

```
patchwork = (ggplot1+ ggplot2 + ggplot3) / (ggplot4 + ggplot5 + ggplot6) 
Final.Plot = patchwork + 
  plot_annotation(tag_levels = 'A')  & theme(legend.position = "bottom") +
  plot_layout(guides = "collect")
```

Error

```
'ncol'  Error: Theme element `ncol` is not defined in the element hierarchy.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ran into the same problem. Turns out the order matters. I got it to work by putting `plot_layout()` before the `plot_annotation()`.

```
patchwork = (ggplot1+ ggplot2 + ggplot3) / (ggplot4 + ggplot5 + ggplot6) 
Final.Plot = patchwork + 
  plot_layout(guides = "collect") +
  plot_annotation(tag_levels = 'A')  & theme(legend.position = "bottom")
```